# How to check if shared memory exists using shmget or ftok?

Tags: c, process, ipc, shared-memory

I am writting project in c using shared memory via shm functions. I want to try to "connect" to shared memory and check if it exists using shmget() function.

I tried a few flags with this function but failed to achieve expected result. I wonder if there is a way to see whether a shared memory already exists.

Comment: Hint: Look at the allowed values for the flags argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`manual page`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html) spells this out rather explicitly.

```
int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
```

> If *shmflg* specifies both **IPC_CREAT** and **IPC_EXCL** and a shared memory segment already exists for key, then **shmget()** fails with *[errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)* set to **EEXIST**.

And again, the flags:

> **IPC_CREAT**
>
> - Create a new segment.  If this flag is not used, then **shmget()** will find the segment associated with *key* and check to see if the user has permission to access the segment.

> **IPC_EXCL**
>
> - This  flag  is  used  with  **IPC_CREAT** to ensure that this call creates the segment.  If the segment already exists, the call fails.

Alternatively, if the flag `IPC_CREAT` is not specified, and no memory segment exists for the given `key`, then `shmget` fails and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`.

> **ENOENT**
>
> - No segment exists for the given *key*, and **IPC_CREAT** was not specified.

So you may want to try something along the lines of

```
errno = 0;

if (-1 == shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL)) {
    if (EEXIST == errno) {
        /* shared memory already exists */
    }
}
```

or

```
errno = 0;

if (-1 == shmget(key, size, 0)) {
    if (ENOENT == errno) {
        /* shared memory does not exist */
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand, [`ftok(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html)  fails for the same reasons as [`stat(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html).